# Implement publish-subscribe pattern using Curator/Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, publish-subscribe, apache-curator

If you have implemented publish-subscribe pattern using Curator/Zookeeper could you please share your experience? We're currently doing proof-of-concept and your feedback would help big time!

Found this [Pub-Sub Example](https://github.com/apache/curator/tree/master/curator-examples/src/main/java/pubsub) link which shows an example using Curator. The note in that example says "it is not meant for production". Are they saying it's not a good pattern to use with Curator and they're only using it as an example to show Curator features? Or are they saying the pattern works well with Curator but the example is not something you would implement in Production?

Would also help to know pros and cons besides the well-known 1MB limitation on a znode size.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the example, *not for prod* warning is probably meant as not to deploy that same code to production. Zookeeper is a great tool for distributed coordination and for storing metadata, but like you noted below, it is not always a good choice as a message queue. Consider using Kafka instead

Answer (score 0):

Came across this [Curator Tech Note](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN4) link which talks about using Zookeeper as a Queue source. Looks like most (if not all) bullets on that page would apply to using ZooKeeper as a publish-subscribe source as well.

So the verdict is ZooKeeper would make a bad publish-subscribe model.